# Nuget add unmanaged files

Tags: nuget, unmanaged

I'm using the following *.targets file to add build actions

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>

        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\libeay32.dll">
            <Link>libeay32.dll</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>

        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\COMAssinaDocs.dll">
            <Link>COMAssinaDocs.dll</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>

        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\InterOps.ComAssinaDocs.dll">
            <Link>InterOps.ComAssinaDocs.dll</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>

        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\ssleay32.dll">
            <Link>ssleay32.dll</Link>
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>

    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and this is the nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>xxx.Providers.SignDocs</id>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="bin\Release\xxx.Providers.SignDocs.targets" target="build" />
        <file src="bin\Release\xxx.Providers.SignDocs.dll" target="lib\net45" />
        <file src="bin\Release\xxx.Providers.SignDocs.Impl.dll" target="lib\net45" />       
  </files>
</package>
```

And I'm using this piece of nuget documentation to build this package:

[Including MSBuild props and targets in a package](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/create-packages/creating-a-package)

Basically what I want is to get a few unmanaged dlls copied to the output folder of the project using the package and even tho I am following the instructions the target project file targets setion iss not added and therefore the files are not copied to the output directory. What am I missing?

> UPDATE

Was able to get it working using the configurations bellow.

xxx.Providers.SignDocs.targets

```
<None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\libeay32.dll">
  <Link>libeay32.dll</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>

<None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\COMAssinaDocs.dll">
  <Link>COMAssinaDocs.dll</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>

<None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\InterOps.ComAssinaDocs.dll">
  <Link>InterOps.ComAssinaDocs.dll</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>

<None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\ssleay32.dll">
  <Link>ssleay32.dll</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>xxx.Providers.SignDocs</id>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\..\tools\libeay32.dll" target="build" />
    <file src="..\..\tools\COMAssinaDocs.dll" target="build" />
    <file src="..\..\tools\InterOps.ComAssinaDocs.dll" target="build" />
    <file src="..\..\tools\ssleay32.dll" target="build" />
    <file src="bin\Release\xxx.Providers.SignDocs.targets" target="build" />
    <file src="bin\Release\xxx.Providers.SignDocs.dll" target="lib\net45" />
    <file src="bin\Release\xxx.Providers.SignDocs.Impl.dll" target="lib\net45" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

The targets file needs to be included in the 'package/files' element of the nuspec file, otherwise it isn't included in the package. It needs a target of 'build'.
The targets file also needs to be named the same as the package.

Comment: I tried this but it does not work         <file src="bin\Release\xxx.Providers.SignDocs.targets" target="build" /> Thanks

Comment: Is the targets file located in the bin\Release folder?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm sure I am missing out something but I can't see what it is.

Comment: The nupkg file is actually just a zip file. Open it up and you should see a 'build' containing your 'targets' file. If it's there and named correctly, a reference to it should be added to the project when installing the package. If the targets file is not in the package, then there's a problem with the nuspec. If the targets file is there, check the project file after the package has been installed to see if it references the targets file.

Comment: I know it is a zip file and I checked it and the files weren't really there. I did a few changes and eventually got it to work. Thanks